# How to pass change reason (django-simple-history) in django admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin, django-simple-history

I use django-simple-history in the project. The documentation https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.0/historical_model.html is clear as to how to pass changeReason value while updating the object. I wonder if it is possible to populate history_change_field when making changes via django admin panel?